# How to save .pdf file with correct filename if specific characters is used in pdftools::pdf_subset(), R

Tags: r, encoding, special-characters, polish, pdftools

I hope someone can help me. I use `pdf_subset()` from `pdftools` package to select some pages from .pdf file and save in new .pdf file. However, there is a problem: my path/filename consists of specific characters (polish letters) which are replaced by other symbols when file saving. How to fix the problem with replacing symbols?
Thanks!

```
library(pdftools)

# extract some pages
pdf_subset('https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf',
           pages = 1:3, output = "FŁŻ_6/Siłaków.pdf")
```

> Blad w poleceniu 'cpp_pdf_select(input, output, pages, password)':
> open C:\Users\PDF\**FĹĹ»_6\SiĹ‚akĂłw.pdf**: No such file or directory

Comment: did you write the output yourself or did you copy from explorer or finder?

Comment: I copied the result, but when I was bolding the path/file, something going wrong. I have already fixed it. Now the message from the console is correct. Thanks!